# summernote not well setup

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, summernote

Hello I am using summernote in my laravel project , all work fine , except in create and edit view there is unnecessary bar () on the top of the page .
my code below :

setup :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/js/vendor/summernote/dist/summernote.css')}}">
 <script src="{{asset('assets/js/vendor/summernote/dist/summernote.js')}}"></script>
```

the html:

```
 <textarea class="form-control summernote"
                  name="special_notes" id="special_notes"
                  placeholder="Enter special notes here...">
            {{ old('special_notes', optional($tblProperty)->special_notes) }}</textarea>
```

the script  :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.summernote').summernote({

            height:300,

        });

    });
```

the unnecessary bar :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i updated the the summernote.js by editing the line 170 adding the css style :
style="display:none !important;" this has fix my problem .

the line became :
   '',

i followed the comment on the link :https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2516

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code try:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
        height:300,
        toolbar: []
    });
```

The code above should remove every toolbar of summernote.

If you want to customize your toolbar to use specific elements then you can fill up the `toolbar` array with the elements you need:

Source : https://summernote.org/deep-dive/

Comment: Did it remove any toolbar of summernote at all? Using above code you shouldn't be able to see any toolbar buttons

Comment: it removed all toolbar except the one i mentioned

Comment: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2516  That's a know issue. Just searched for it as well. Have a look in here